# Rails: "7.Times do" for days of the week

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to add attributes for each weekday. Here's what I have at the moment:

```
7.times do |i|
        t = user.my_weekdays.build
        t.the_day = "#{i}"
end
```

Now, what I'd like to do is to set the attribute `the_day` for each day (ex. Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday)

How would I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't recheck it myself but you can try to use `Date::DAYNAMES` see [doc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html)

```
7.times do |i|
    t = user.my_weekdays.build
    t.the_day = Date::DAYNAMES[i]
end
```

PS be carefull according to documentation the first day is "Sunday"